# Hacer que mi sitio se abra en modo escritorio para moviles

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

¡Hola! Estoy programando un sitio web sencillo, ahora me toca diseñar la plantilla para moviles, pero mientras hacia esto me di cuenta de que, al poner el navegador del movil en "Modo para escritorio" mostraba la pagina como quiero que se muestre en moviles, asi que mi pregunta es:
**¿Como puedo hacer que mi sitio en moviles se abra como escritorio?**

No parece que se pueda hacer, pero tengo una pequeña esperanza de que sea posible, asi que pregunto por aqui en caso de que si haya una manera.

**Edit, disculpen por tardar**

Este es el metaviewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Mi codigo tiene un diseño responsive, pero no me gusta tanto como se ve en comparacion a cuando se pone la opcion "ver como ordenador".

Imagine que un codigo javascript podria hacer que la funcion "ver como ordenador" este activada predefinidamente al entrar al sitio, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Tengo entendido que si el sitio web tiene un diseño reponsive o adaptable a cada tipo de pantalla, al momento de clickear en la opción del navegador donde dice "Ver como ordenador" debería colocarlo automáticamente.

Comment: Hola!, sería bueno que compartieras tu código HTML y CSS para tener un poco más de contexto y así poder ayudarte de una mejor manera, sino estaríamos adivinando

Comment: Tienes agregada una etiqueta `<meta name="viewport" content="....">` en el header? puedes compartir el codigo de esta linea?

Comment: ya pase el metaviewport, que deberia hacer?

Comment: quería saber si ya conseguiste que tu sitio web se vea por defecto "sitio de escritorio" en móvil, ya que quisiera saber exactamente lo mismo. Gracias!

Comment: yo tenía la misma problemática y lo resolví comentando la etiqueta de meta viewport, de modo que el navegador no intentara escalar el sitio automáticamente, no es la mejor respuesta ni la más elegante, pero funciona.